# In sql when i use 'group by' after making one of the columns as primary key, it's not showing the output in desired groups?

Tags: mysql, computer-science, rdbms

```
alter table dependent\n
add constraint con_second primary key(Bdate);\n
```

As some of u asked for the full query here i am giving it.
This is the query to retrieve Fnames of all employees having more than 2 daughters.Hope now it's clear.And order by can't be used here.

> Blockquote

```
   Select Fname from EMPLOYEE2 where Ssn in (select Essn from dependent 
   group by Essn,relationship having COUNT(relationship)>2 AND relationship="daughter";

987654321   Spouse
333445555   Spouse
123456789   Spouse
333445555   Son
333445555   Daughter
123456789   Son
123456789   Daughter
```

As can be seen the above table is neither grouped by Essn nor by Relationship.As i can find out it's showing the output in increasing order of Bdate which is primary key here.

Comment: What is the output you expect? (And what is the sample data of your table?)

Comment: What SQL query are you running? The primary key of the table has nothing to do with whether or not the results will be grouped. If you are grouping on the PK in your query, you will get one row per PK value—just as if you had not grouped at all—because each group will only have one row.

Comment: There is no aggregation here so I doubt that group by is very useful. Perhaps you want order by,

Comment: When i remove primary key(Bdate) constraint, the result is table grouped by Essn and then relationship,but when i add this constraint the output becomes distorted as shown in above table.

Answer (score 0):

Group by and order by are two entirely different things. In your query the group by is on both selected fields which will have no effect unless there are duplicate rows. For example if I duplicate the last row your query

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(essn int, relationship varchar(20));
insert into t values
(987654321 ,  'Spouse'),
(333445555 ,  'Spouse'),
(123456789 ,  'Spouse'),
(333445555 ,  'Son'),
(333445555 ,  'Daughter'),
(123456789 ,  'Son'),
(123456789 ,  'Daughter'),
(123456789 ,  'Daughter');

select Essn,relationship from t group by Essn,relationship;
```

Drops the duplicate

```
+-----------+--------------+
| Essn      | relationship |
+-----------+--------------+
| 123456789 | Daughter     |
| 123456789 | Son          |
| 123456789 | Spouse       |
| 333445555 | Daughter     |
| 333445555 | Son          |
| 333445555 | Spouse       |
| 987654321 | Spouse       |
+-----------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The same thing can be (and is better) achieved by using DISTINCT

```
select distinct essn,relationship from t;
+-----------+--------------+
| essn      | relationship |
+-----------+--------------+
| 987654321 | Spouse       |
| 333445555 | Spouse       |
| 123456789 | Spouse       |
| 333445555 | Son          |
| 333445555 | Daughter     |
| 123456789 | Son          |
| 123456789 | Daughter     |
+-----------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice that in both cases the result is in no particular order - you need to use ORDER BY to achive that

```
select distinct essn,relationship from t order by essn,relationship;
+-----------+--------------+
| essn      | relationship |
+-----------+--------------+
| 123456789 | Daughter     |
| 123456789 | Son          |
| 123456789 | Spouse       |
| 333445555 | Daughter     |
| 333445555 | Son          |
| 333445555 | Spouse       |
| 987654321 | Spouse       |
+-----------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The addition of a key only helps performance you still need the order by.
If there are no duplicates in your data the the DISTINCT clause (and the GROUP BY) is irrelevant and you just need an order by.

Comment: "Notice that in both cases the result is in no particular order" - But the first result (GROUP BY) **is** sorted. This behavior depends on the used version and is optimizer related. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html): "GROUP BY sorting is a MySQL extension that may change in a future release". This "feature" was depricated in 5.7 and removed in 8.0